# Anyone helps me understand a sentence below?

Tags: meaning

In a recent article, I didn't fully understand the meaning of "on the books" in this context. Anyone with interests in ongoing presidential elections in the United States cares to enlighten me?

MCEVERS: And, Tamara, Bernie Sanders is not campaigning today. He went home to Vermont. Does this mean he is slowing down?

KEITH: Well, he's slowing down at least for 24 hours. ***His campaign insists that this was just a day to recharge and it's been on the books for a while and that he will have more events very soon,*** including - they've announced three events tomorrow. But there's no denying that the loss in New York and the size of the loss in New York is a devastating hit to his campaign.

Comment: "on the books" = planned

Comment: The phrase "it's been on the books" in this context means "it has been scheduled." In other words, the speaker is saying that the candidate's day off from campaigning reflects a scheduling decision made some time ago and does not constitute a reaction to the candidate's setback in the most recent (New York) primary election or represent a crucial pause introduced to give him time to reassess the viability of his candidacy.

Comment: Meanwhile "a day of recharge" means "a day of rest and recuperation"—although the metaphorical image is of a depleted battery being given a transfusion of energy from an outside electrical source.

Comment: The idiom "on the books" has a half-dozen different meanings, but in the sense used above it means "planned" (as in "written in the 'book' that is used to keep track of planned events").  The idiom can also, eg, refer to a law that has been written, has passed whatever legislative body needs to "bless" it, and is, in effect, written in the books of law that an attorney would consult.  There is also a flavor of the term in sports, referring to records from past games.

Answer (score 1):

"On the books" here means "scheduled." The speaker is saying, don't read too much into the fact that Bernie has taken a day off from campaigning, that this break was planned long ago, and does not mean that he is "slowing down." Just as you might schedule a day off from your job to recharge, as opposed to calling in sick at the last moment.